Science fiction book about kids trying to survive an alien attack
This book was about aliens invading Earth and a group of children are trying to survive and defeat them.

The main character (a young male) falls in love with one of the girls in the group and at the end the aliens capture both of them and she almost dies as the aliens torture them in the ocean.

I believe they have a child together toward the end of the book.

I think it had a purple cover.



You could improve this Story-Identification question by going through the checklists here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

For example; When did you read this book? How old were the kids? What were their names? What was the name of the aliens? How did they get to Earth? Was there any organised resistance against the aliens? How, precisely, were they tortured in the ocean? Was this book aimed at kids or adults? What language did you read it in?

What about adults? Where are they, why do they have to fight children? Are all the adults dead? Or are the children simply a group of survivors?

Was it a  hard back book (like you would get from a library, and thus a plain purple cover) or a paperback with a design or picture on it that was mostly a purpleish color.

I was messaged re this thread to comment on whether it’s ’Inish Carraig’ (disclosure - I’m the author) as there is some commonality. Inish is set in Northern Ireland, has teenagers fighting aliens, and a scene with a dead alien baby. Not sure if that helps
